# Create custom product image editing options

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-options

I have a requirement to build a magento site with customize option for products as given in http://fineartamerica.com/products/mona-lisa-leonardo-da-vinci-framed-print.html . How can I achieve this. Searched many in net but couldn't find the one.

Comment: How you add "new" label,  https://snag.gy/IGKZs5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't get exact feature look-wise but can get functionality-wise  simply create configurable products with custom options... 
the given website core php work So i you need exactly you have to create a extension for that..  follow this [link](http://insync.co.in/how-to-create-custom-options-configurable-products-in-magento/)